# Creating a UNIX shell

Tags: shell, unix

I want to create a mini shell for UNIX just to know the ins and outs of everything. I am having some confusions understanding things that I used to get for granted. This is kinda philosophical question. When I creating a "shell", I assume I have a UNIX with no shell, so what would be the std in and std out in this case? doesnt functions like system() and exec() use the shell to execute programs, so if I am creating a shell in the first place. How do these functions work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several functions in the `exec` family: `execve(2)`, `execl(3)`, `execle(3)`, `execlp(3)`, `execv(3)`, `execvp(3)`. The first one, `execve(2)` is provided by the operating system kernel as a system call. (Well, okay, the function that programs call is provided by the system C library, but *it* is a simple wrapper around the system call.) The other functions provide slightly different semantics and are implemented in terms of the `execve(2)` function.

The shells could use `execvp(3)` or `execlp(3)` to provide the `PATH` search for executables, but at least `bash(1)` *hashes* the full pathname of executables to provide a performance benefit. (See `bash(1)` built-in `hash` for details.)

`system(3)` is implemented via `/bin/sh -c`, as you've surmised.

The standard input and output is set up by whichever program spawned the shell. If a user logs in on the console directly, it'll be handled by `agetty(8)` or `mgetty(8)` or whichever `getty`-alike program handles direct logins. If a user logs in via `sshd(8)`, then `sshd(8)` is in charge of creating the `pty` and delegating the terminal slave to the shell. If a user creates their shells via `xterm(1)` or other terminal emulators, then those processes will be responsible for hooking up the standard input, output, and error for the shell.

Answer (score 3):

`system(3)` does indeed use (possibly directly or indirectly via exec) a shell to do its work.  `exec(3)` and friends, however, do not use a shell, but rather execute the specified program image directly.  You can see this simply by reading their respective `man` pages.

One difference is that with system(), you will see sugar like wildcards being expanded, whereas if you pass `*` as an argument to your program using exec(), your program will see the literal asterisk (and probably not know what to do).

A shell can be implemented using exec() among other things.  It gets its stdin and stdout from something called the TTY (teletype, or old-school terminal) or PTY (pseudo-terminal, as in modern systems).  See `posix_openpt(2)`.