# Creating a customised shell

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have created a customized shell in C++. Currently, the shell is designed as an infinite while loop that is started by running the corresponding executable from the terminal (I am using Ubuntu as my OS). The shell implements a few new commands that are each stored as separate executables in the file system. The rest of the commands that the user enters are directly executed using the `execve()` wrapper function.

So, essentially, I am executing all the user commands by using the execve() function: the customised commands are stored as separate exectuables and are "`exec`ed" by providing the path to the executable whereas any other "standard" unix command is directly `exec`ed.

Instead of running it as a separate executable from `bash`, I want to ***make the user use my shell*** that ***executes on the terminal***. How can I do that?

I referred to the following links:

[Processes and Sessions and Controlling Terminals](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html)

[Creating a UNIX shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161390/creating-a-unix-shell)

However, I am unable to figure to out the links like association between a controlling terminal and the shell etc. Any help would be appreciated in this regards.

**UPDATE:**

This may sound a bit illogical but:

*Is there any way to implement it as a user command that the user can execute from the current shell?I know there is a command called chsh... but will it work with my shell?*

Comment: You need some process that forks your shell. Does it really matter what process that is? Be it bash, any other shell, or some booting step? Just register your shell as the users login shell, maybe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: When you say "separate terminal", do you mean a separate `gnome-terminal`, or do you want to default all terminals to be your shell?

Comment: @arkascha: That sounds like a good idea but I actually forgot to mention on thing and so made an update... Can you look into that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that update. What do you mean by that? Why can't the user simply execute your shell?

Comment: @arkascha : Sorry a typo..I actually wanted the user to use my shell instead... Editing it...

Comment: @merlin2011: Sorry a typo..I actually wanted the user to use my shell instead... Editing it... –

Comment: If your shell can be executed then _it is a command_. What is the issue here?

Comment: @arkascha: This might be a bit illogical but: I want to implement it as command that when run from the a terminal that currently executes a shell like bash, replaces bash and the user instead uses my customised shell.. I know there is a command called chsh... but will it work with my shell?

Comment: Sorry, but I have the impression you should take a look into how user sessions in unixoid systems work, how shells get invoked, so about the process tree. Your issue dies not really exist, if I understood your question correct.

Comment: The shell is held in the right-most field for the user in /etc/passwd, just change that or (better) create a test username using your new shell.

Answer (score 1):

First you can test your shell from bash with `exec yourshell`. This *replaces* the bash process with your shell entirely. (When you exit your shell, the terminal will exit/logout with it.)

You can also run `xterm -e yourshell` to start an xterm with your shell instead of bash.

If you want to permanently make it your default shell:

1. Add your shell to the list of system shells, `/etc/shells`
2. Change your user's login shell with `chsh`
3. Log out and in again